# Is there a way to do :not(something or somethingelse)

Tags: css

An example will speak for itself

```css
.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:not(.yellow), li:not(.green) {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cyan">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="green">green</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
</ul>
```

I want to cyan and yellow to stay black. I know there are ways arround but that is not what I'm looking for.

I want to do :not(.yellow or .green)

Comment: People may be able to suggest better approaches to styling if you hadn’t used generic class names. Instead, you’re just going to get answers on how to “hack” your way around this CSS shortcoming, rather than suggestions on how to avoid the situation altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your `:not` negation selectors together:

```css
.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:not(.yellow):not(.green) {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cyan">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="green">green</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can do it

```
li:not(.yellow):not(.green) {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:not(.yellow):not(.green) {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cyan">red</li>
  <li class="red">red</li>
  <li class="green">green</li>
  <li class="blue">blue</li>
  <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
</ul>
```